How to make only specific group can logon to a domain computer?
I want only users that are members of a specific group to be able to logon to a computer.
How do we do this using
Group Policy?

You should add the group to this policy:
Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Allow log on locally

Remember to Link the Created GPO to domain controllers

Nothing in the question talks about domain controllers, and you would not want to apply such a policy to DCs - it should be linked to the OU that contains the required computer account(s). Also, by default, members of the local Users group are included in the "Allow log on locally" policy  - you would need to remove Users from the policy at the same time you add the AD group. Do not remove Administrators from the policy list.
